# Customize DatePicker to select year and month

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

The current JavaFX implementation of a DatePicker only allows you to select a year and month by clicking the < > buttons.  Most modern implementations of DatePicker allow you to select the year for example like this:

[image]

How do we get this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

So far I have not seen a datepicker with that feature in JavaFX. Neither the javafx.scene.control.DatePicker nor the ControlsFX- and JFXtras-controls have such a functionality as far as I know (ControlsFX even doesn't provide a datepicker to my knowledge).

However on http://calendarcontrolinjavafx.blogspot.com/2012/01/calendar-control-in-javafx-20.html there is a custom datepicker with such a functionality (but with a different style) together with a demo application.

Unfortunately the implementation is from 2012 and is in JavaFX 2. However, with minimal changes it runs with >= JavaFX 8. Below are a few snapshots. I have no idea concerning the stability but maybe it's worth a try.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you needed a year picker or a year-month picker but I assume the latter. I also needed one for year-months and could not find anything that works for javafx 8 or above so I wrote one: https://github.com/perNyfelt/fx-yearmonth-picker.

Comment: This is good, but I actually needed to select a specific day, but without having to click 50 times to get to year 1970.